# Node can be replaced by a "TextView" with compound drawables

Tags: android, xml

I am just starting on android development. Using the layout editor I added a Image View below the TextView.
By after adding the TextView the following warning was printed:

```
Node view can be replaced by a "TextView" with compound drawables
This tag and its children can be replaced by one <TextView/> and a compound drawable  A LinearLayout which contains an ImageView and a TextView can be more efficiently handled as a compound drawable (a single TextView, using the drawableTop, drawableLeft, drawableRight and/or drawableBottom attributes to draw one or more images adjacent to the text).  If the two widgets are offset from each other with margins, this can be replaced with a drawablePadding attribute.  There's a lint quickfix to perform this conversion in the Eclipse plugin.  Issue id: UseCompoundDrawables
```

Please help me resolve this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning says *"can be replaced by"* not *"should be replaced by"*. So you can ignore it. Not every `ImageView` and `TextView` combo can be replaced by `CompoundDrawables`. Even then let me if you want to know, how to do this, I have described it below.

`TextView` tag comes with 4 compound drawables, one for each of `left`, `top`, `right` and `bottom`.

Just add below line to your TextView.

`android:drawableLeft="@drawable/up_count_big"`

Or in java code, you can do it like this:-

```
mTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
```

where `left` ,`top` ,`right` and `bottom` are all drawables.

See [TextView#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) for more info.